# Connection String in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, connection-string, sql-server-2017

My connection is okay with the data source, so it gives me the errors here :

> Fill SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

How can I fix that? This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sqlSelect = "select * from account" +
                       "Where username ='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and password ='" + txtPassword.Text + " ' ";

    // khoi tao doi tuong command
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, InitCon)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.Text
            };

    // khoi tao doi tuong adapter
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    // tao datable chua data
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // su dung adapter do data vao table nay
    adapter.Fill(dt);     // error occurs near here

    // binding eridview voi table
    dgwAccount.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Well, what is the SELECT command you're trying to put into the data table?

Comment: The select command is data source of the connection string I have created here:            string sqlSelect = "select * from account" +
                "Where username ='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and password ='" + txtPassword.Text + " ' ";
            // khoi tao doi tuong command
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, InitCon)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.Text
            };

Comment: And how do `dt` or `adapter` how about this query? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: I have edited it. Can you help me pls

Comment: You didn't add anything. Please show your code as text, not images

Comment: In particular, when you post your source, include the part where you create the connection from the connection string

Comment: can you give me an example, please?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @marc_s I know it can include the error of sql injection but here, I must learn the code with the code of my teachers has show me. So how can I fix this errors : 'The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.'

Comment: @PhạmThông, ask your teachers why they are not using parameterized queries. If they are not familiar with parameterized queries, they should be learning instead of teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below, it solves several issues with your code:

- prevents from [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) risk,
- handles unmanaged resources by using `using` keyword,
- also adds space in text of your query between `account` and `where`, which you forgot.

See below code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
    {
        com.CommandText = "select * from account " + //don't forget about space here!
                                  "where username = @username and password = @password";
        com.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
        com.Connection = conn;

        using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
        {
            conn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helpful, then I will try.

Answer (score 0):

you should open db connection before execute command.  i suggest take a look  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a(v=vs.110).aspx). also i put here a sample code and i hope this helps you:

```
private static void CreateCommand(string query,string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader[0], reader[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I fix the errors show here:'The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.'

Comment: i cant see connection.Open(); and connection.Close(); instructions around of adapter.Fill(dt); !  and also please show more details about  "InitCon"

Answer (score 0):

As seen from the code snippet, InitCon varibale is not initialized, you might wanna check that...

For more reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx